# How to use Magic Mouse with SolidWorks on Parallels 9

Tags: parallels, magic-mouse, solidworks

How can I use the "middle button" function on Magic Mouse to rotate 3D objects? I am running Solidworks on Parallels.

Answer (score 1):

I spend a lot of time trying to make it work, and I found a simple option that helped me a lot!

The second option on Preferences > Shortcuts > Mouse Shortcuts >  "Click with middle button" (or something similar, mine is in portuguese)

Now I can just hold COMMAND and use the left click to rotate.

Edit: Preferences on Parallels, right click on parallels ICON then, Preferences > Mouse > Click with middle button. Then you can use the Command button to rotate with mouse click.

Answer (score 0):

couldn't see the preferences wagner was referring to (Solidworks?mouse?where?).. however; set up the right click gesture to toggle "rotate". works well once used to it.
Now all we need is for someone to write a driver that allows the magic mouse swipe to rotate a view...

Comment: Welcome to Super User! This is really a comment and **not** an answer to the original question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: Hi David! The preferences on Parallels, right click on parallels ICON then, Preferences > Mouse > Click with middle button.

Then you can use the Command button to rotate with mouse click.

Please upvote if it works!

Answer (score 0):

I found it!
In the Parallels top menu. Click on Actions > Configure > Hardware > Mouse & Keyboard > Open Shortcuts Preferences > Check Middle Click